# radius of convergence of hypergeometric functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-matrices

Hypergeometric function of scalar arguments is defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
    _aF_b\left(p_1,...,p_a;q_1,...,q_b;z\right) &=&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(p_1\right)_i...\left(p_a\right)_i}{\left(q_1\right)_i...\left(q_b\right)_i}\frac{z^i}{i!}
\end{eqnarray}
In general, it is told that if $a\le b+1$, and if $z$ is finite, then the radius of convergence is $\infty$. But I am facing a problem. I am trying to calculate $_1F_1\left(1,2,10^6\right)$, but the series diverges. Such high values of $z$ can occur in stochastic systems, where the noise$\left(\text{variance}\left(\sigma^2\right) = 1e-6\right)$ is very low and $z = \frac{\text{some finite value between 0 and 1}}{\sigma^2}$. One can see that in this case, $z$ is finite and $a\le b$, but the function still diverges. So, is there anything that I am missing here regarding the conditions for the radius of convergence?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't ${}_1F_1(1;2;z) = \frac{e^z - 1}{z}$ ???

Comment: That's true. $_1F_1\left(1;2;z\right)$ is $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$. And one can see that for any positive finite value of $z$, numerator increases exponentially, while increase in denominator is linear. So, the series diverges. But as per the convergence conditions, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: That's not true, the series still converges. The problem is as $z$ getting larger and larger, the largest term in the series appear later and later. For example, when you expand $e^z$ as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$, the largest term appear at $k \sim |z|$. When you compute something at $10^6$, you need to sum through the first $10^6$ terms before you start to see the series converges.

Comment: For very large and positive $z$, you should consider using the asymptotic expansion of ${}_1F_1(a;b,z) = M(a,b,z)$ instead. e.g. those in [DLMF 13.7](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.7).